# Authenticating without sending password to the server, and store data encrypted with password derived key on server

Tags: symmetric, authentication, password-hashing, password-based-encryption

I am trying to think of a scheme that would allow a user to authenticate to a server, whithout sending the password to the server, and to also derive a symetric key on the client (that also never gets sent to the server), the sym key would be used to encrypt and decrypt data on the client,that gets saved encrypted on the server.

#### The question is: how robust is the following scheme ?

The client is implemented in javascript, runs in a browser that is assumed to produce good random seed data, and the connection is through TLS.

1. authenticate without sending the password to the server
2. derive a symetric key from the password, that never gets sent to the server
3. store data on the server encrypted with

#### On the client:

```
symKey = scrypt(password, salt)
authKey = scrypt(symKey, salt)
```

#### On the server:

```
// when the account is created, the server hashes authKey 
// again, and saves it with its salt

authHash = scrypt(authKey, salt2)

database.save([userId, authHash, salt2])
```

the user then encrypts data using symKey, that gets saved on the database:

```
userRowInDatabase[id, authHash, salt2, dataEncryptedWith(symKey)]
```

- hasing would be done with Scrypt
- Symetric encryption would be done with TweetNACL Secretbox (Based on XSalsa20 stream cipher and Poly1305 one-time authenticator)

Comment: Did you forget to put a question? On the client-side use two different salts. Also, you can use the password to derive different keys with different salts.

Comment: What is your question? What kind of help you expect here?

Comment: @kelalaka, the question is "how good is the scheme". I added it to the text, the title is already pretty long

Comment: The [OPAQUE protocol](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-krawczyk-cfrg-opaque-02) may be a solution for you.